# iPhone app upload problems

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, upload, appstore-approval

Hi :) i just done making an app.. but when i want to upload the binary file i got 3 fail

1. Icon specified in the info.plist not found under top level app wrapper: icon.png
2. Iphone/Ipod Touch: info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found. You MinimumOSVersion is below 3.2, so you must define CFBundleIconFil...
3. Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission cerficate

(application loader)

what can i do?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my guesses on fixing your 3 issues. Correct me if I'm wrong on any of this guys.

1. You need to add your icon as a 57x57 .png file, and make sure that the icon value in info.plist matches icon.png.
2. Set your minimun OS requirement in info.plist or the build settings to be HIGHER or EQUAL to OS 3.2
3. Go to the developer provisioning portal:
   http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action

Get a new **Distribution** certificate. You need to code sign with a distribution certificate in xcode, creating a **release version**. Then it won't give you an invalid signature message.

Comment: what do you mean with :  icon value in info.plist matches icon.png.

Comment: The plist looks like a two column table. The left column will say icon file, and the corresponding right column will say the file name. That should be set to icon.png.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this checklist. It helped me get apps submitted:

http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/checklist.html

Comment: And you did all the stuff under item 3 in that checklist?